# Send Google Sheet via e-mail and run the related script on a device (like Excel with VBA modlues)

Tags: android, google-apps-script, offline

I've created a excel survey with checkboxes. Each checkbox is a answer that is use in a simple macro for check the answers and calculate a score.
Usually I send this file to the people with e-mail, they compile it and send me back the file.
The problem is that VBA macro works only with Windows and not with android devices.
So I've created the same sheet in Google Sheets and I've reproduced the same VBA code in Google App Script, with the hope to use it on android devices and give to the people more flexibility.
This works in my Drive area both with my windows PC and my android tablet.
What I want now is to use my script also offline and not only in my drive, because I need to send the Google sheet to people and let them to run my script also if they have not access to my Google Drive (like I do now with excel files).
Is this something that Google sheet can do?
Can I send Google Sheet with script inside that I can run also without internet connection and without connection to my Drive?
thanks for support

Comment: Can't you do this with native formula's? No it is not like excel... i just tried it but it did not work.

Comment: Google Apps Script only runs on a server.